# Pygame_Python - screen opens and closes immediately

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a maze interface with two stimuli flashing at right and left side. The code runs, opens the interface and closes immediately. I know it is because the loop is not running properly. Since I am a beginner in Python, I can't really find where the bug is.

Can anyone take a look and help me resolve this error?

```
import sys; sys.path.append('..') 
import pygame
from flicky import FlickyManager
import open_bci_v3 as bci
import os
import logging
import time
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy
from collections import *
import math
import pandas as pd
import brain

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cursor Control by SSVEP')

done = False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
flickymanager = FlickyManager(screen)

# 7.5 Hz
flickymanager.add('left',8.33)
# 12. 5 Hz
flickymanager.add('right',5) 

exit = False

playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.bmp')

def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

x = 250
y = 90
x_change = 0

def maze():
    M = 10
    N = 9
    maze = [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ]
    bx = 0
    by = 0
    for i in range(0, M * N):
        if maze[ bx + (by * M) ] == 1:
            gameDisplay.blit(blockImg,( 200 + bx * 40 , 40 + by * 40 ))
        bx = bx + 1
        if bx == M:
            bx = 0 
            by = by + 1

while not exit and while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                done = True

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
            done = True

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(60) # 16 ms between frames ~ 60FPS
    flickymanager.process()
    flickymanager.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()

    if brain.headto() == 'right':
        x_change = 20
    elif brain.headto() == 'left':
        x_change = -20
    elif brain.headto() == 'stay':
        x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    player(x,y)
    maze()

    pygame.display.update()



pygame.quit()
```

This is the snippet of another module called flicky.py which I called in the main code:

```
class FlickyManager:
    def __init__(self,screen):
        self.flickies = []
        self.screen = screen
    def addFlicky(self,f):
        self.flickies.append(f)
    def add(self,location,frames):
        w, h = self.screen.get_size()
        if location == 'left':
            x = 0; y = h / 2 - A/2;
        elif location == 'right':
            x = w - A; y = h / 2 - A/2;
        elif location == 'top':
            y = 0; x = w / 2 - A/2;
        elif location == 'bottom':
            y = h-A; x = w / 2 - A/2;
        else:
            raise ValueError("location %s unknown" % location)
        f = Flicky(x,y,frames)
        self.flickies.append(f)
    def process(self):
        for f in self.flickies:
            f.process()
    def draw(self):
        for f in self.flickies:
            f.draw(self.screen)
```

This defines the brain module:

```
def headto( ):
    board.start_streaming(getsample, 1.5)
    average7_5 = numpy.mean(e7_5Output)
    average12_5 = numpy.mean(e12_5Output)
    print average7_5
    print average12_5
    average = (average7_5 + average12_5)/2
    print average
    if  10000 < average < 30000:
       return "right"
    elif 30000 <= average < 60000:
       return "left"
    else:
       return "stay"
```

Sorry for the mess here. But basically what i am trying to do is to combine the below two packages into one. To have a maze screen in the middle and two flickering boards at left and right. I am able to run the packages one by one successfully but when i combined, it is not getting displayed together. I am just a beginner in coding and that is why the code is getting messed.

This is the first package, where two stimuli flickers:

```
import pygame #@UnusedImport
from flicky import FlickyManager

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([800,200])
pygame.display.set_caption("Stimulus")

done=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
flickymanager = FlickyManager(screen)

# 7.5 Hz
flickymanager.add('left',8.33)
# 12. 5 Hz
flickymanager.add('right',5) 


while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                done = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(60) # 16 ms between frames ~ 60FPS
    flickymanager.process()
    flickymanager.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

This is the second package of maze layout.

```
import sys; sys.path.append('..') 
import pygame
import open_bci_v3 as bci
import os
import logging
import time
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy
from collections import *
import math
import pandas as pd
import brain

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Maze Game by SSVEP')

white = (255,255,255)

exit = False
playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.bmp')
blockImg = pygame.image.load('block.bmp')

def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

x = 250
y = 90
x_change = 0

def maze():
    M = 10
    N = 9
    maze = [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
             1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ]
    bx = 0
    by = 0
    for i in range(0, M * N):
        if maze[ bx + (by * M) ] == 1:
            gameDisplay.blit(blockImg,( 200 + bx * 40 , 40 + by * 40 ))
        bx = bx + 1
        if bx == M:
            bx = 0 
            by = by + 1

while not exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True

    if brain.headto() == 'right':
        x_change = 20
    elif brain.headto() == 'left':
        x_change = -20
    elif brain.headto() == 'stay':
        x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    player(x,y)
    maze()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to combine both of these into one? For me a screen with two boards is the only thing coming. I am not able to display the maze screen. Any help would be great. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the statement at the end of the code snippit closes the application. Is it meant to be indented?

Comment: Yes it is. I commented it and checked, that is not making any difference.

Comment: @skrx I have made the indentations correct, I am not sure where the bug is in the code as it just runs the code, pygame window flashes and closes. That is why I have put the entire code.

Comment: First off, try considering making your code Object Oriented. So use classes in which you handle just a certain job with it's def's. This way your code will be much clearer to read and you can find any bugs much easier. Secondly, why are you constantly drawing the map over and over? That seems like a bit too much, why not just draw it once and draw the player when needed with a Update function.

Comment: The code example is still not complete and verifiable. You have to tell us what `flicky` and `brain` are. I've just tried to reduce your code to the minimum and fixed the things that Charlton Lane mentioned, and the program seems to work correctly now (with the flicky and brain stuff commented out).

Comment: @skrx I will update in the main section what flicky and brain modules are. Thanks.

Comment: There are still several missing items: `board`, `e7_5Output`, `e12_5Output` and `Flicky`. I've tried to comment out or replace the missing variables again and the program doesn't crash or close immediately. What error messages do you see when you run your program from the command-line/terminal? BTW, remove the `quit()` at the end, because it should only be used to quit the shell.

Comment: @skrx Now I see a window opening with two rectangles at the sides, value is read from the board(which takes brain signal), but there is no maze layout in the middle.

Comment: @skrx I forked the code available on Github https://github.com/Alice-Ke/SSVEP. what I am trying to do is combine stimulus.py and maze.py into one package. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's really a lot of code and I'm not sure if I can help you. Especially the `OpenBCIBoard` class is huge, so it would take a lot of time to analyze the code. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: @skrx Actually, you need not consider that class much here in this code. It's the stuff to analyze the brain waves and they have the board and headset to connect. I am just working to see if I can combine stimulus.py and maze.py together into one code. For OpenBCI, here is the link http://docs.openbci.com/Getting%20Started/00-Welcome. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the line:

`while not exit and while done == False:`

it should probably be:

`while not exit and not done:`

When drawing the line `screen.fill((0,0,0))`, it is referencing `screen` which doesnt exist, I think you want to use `gameDisplay` instead.

`brain` is also never defined and so will throw an error when calling `brain.headto()`.

`blockImg` also never appears to be defined.

These issues are causing the program to crash immediately after starting.
To see any errors that are causing the program to crash, run the code through IDLE or an IDE rather than running the .py file as this will usually provide feedback about the crash.

Also, it would be recommended use another variable name other than `exit` as this can have special meanings in python.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have fixed the syntax error and defined `blockImg`. Also in the main section I have defined the modules flicky.py which defines the screen. Now running the code again, I am getting following error:     `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ali_modified.py", line 25, in <module>
    flickymanager = FlickyManager(screen)
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Check out if this example works as intended. I couldn't test it with the `brain` module and just used the arrow keys instead.

```
import pygame as pg

import brain
from flicky import FlickyManager


def maze():
    M = 10
    N = 9
    maze = [
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
        1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,
        1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
        1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        ]

    bx = 0
    by = 0
    for i in range(0, M * N):
        if maze[ bx + (by * M) ] == 1:
            screen.blit(blockImg,( 200 + bx * 40 , 40 + by * 40 ))
        bx = bx + 1
        if bx == M:
            bx = 0
            by = by + 1


pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 800))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

white = (255, 255, 255)

playerImg = pg.image.load('player.bmp').convert()
blockImg = pg.image.load('block.bmp').convert()

flickymanager = FlickyManager(screen)
flickymanager.add('left',8.33)  # 7.5 Hz
flickymanager.add('right',5)  # 12. 5 Hz

x = 250
y = 90
x_change = 0

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    if brain.headto() == 'right':
        x_change = 20
    elif brain.headto() == 'left':
        x_change = -20
    elif brain.headto() == 'stay':
        x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    flickymanager.process()

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill(white)
    maze()
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
    flickymanager.draw()

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for modifying the code and sharing. I ran it with my OpenBCI board connected and i am getting following error: `Board Instantiated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newcursor.py", line 40, in <module>
    playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.bmp')
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
Closing Serial...`   could you let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Oh, I just renamed `pygame` to `pg` in the example (`import pygame as pg`), but then I copied and pasted the old `pygame.image.load` lines into the example and forgot to rename them. Just rename `pygame` to `pg` as well or change everything back to `pygame`. BTW, you should usually convert images `playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.bmp').convert()` or `.convert_alpha()`, since that improves the blit performance.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) It worked. The screen pops up now as I expected. But running stimulus.py alone, the checkerboards used to flicker at the frequencies defined, whereas now, it does not flicker. I am trying to move the block in maze to left and right using the brain waves (on concentrating to frequencies with which checkerboard flicker, I get same brain wave).

Comment: Also, adding convert() gives me unicode error. `File"/Users/divz/Documents/Alice_ky_Trail1/open_bci_v3.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.print_incoming_text()
File "/Users/divz/Documents/Alice_ky_Trail1/open_bci_v3.py", line 322, in print_incoming_text
    c = self.ser.read().decode('utf-8')
  File "/Users/divz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: That's strange. Is this error really caused by `.convert()` or anything else?

Comment: I guess so, If i run the script without convert(), it works. Also, do you know in the new code stimulus (checkerboards) don't flicker?

Comment: Does [this version](https://pastebin.com/0TzJezPr) flicker as you want? I've just put the `FlickyManager` and `Flicky` into the same file as the rest of the code and it seems to work correctly. I'm not sure why it doesn't flicker for you, so we have to investigate.

Comment: I will check it out with connecting the board and let you know, Thanks!